# Antarctic data in Earth Engline Landsat 8/9 collections

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to use Landsat collection 8, to look at a feature in Antarctica. Specifically this collection https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2 although I also checked the tier 1 and 2 surface reflectance products and raw image products. I am little stumped because there doesn't appear to be Antarctic data in any of these collections. I checked by running

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()

mgtLoc = ee.Geometry.Point([165.01,-80.00])
res=100 #thermal resolution
collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2").filterDate('2015-06-01', '2016-06-01').filterBounds(
    mgtLoc)
print(collection.size().getInfo())
```

which returns 0 indicating that there isn't any data available. I even tried making a map just to showing the median pixel value as a way to see where there is Landsat data and there doesn't appear to be any available past around 70 south (made with this simple notebook https://github.com/firstkingofrome/RS_Thermal_final_project/commits/main/showLandsatTracks.ipynb ).

[image: Landsat 8 image availability]

Does anyone know what is up with this or if this data is available in Earth Engine in some other collection (there is definitely Landsat 8 imagery of Antarctica)?

Updated 5/3/22:
I ended up contacting google support and they determined that these images are in the LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T2_L2 collection.

Comment: Check [Landsat Archive Dashboard](https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-archive-dashboard) for querying for a specific path/row. If you can't find a specific scene, maybe it's because GEE. Check on EarthExplorer or other DAACto be sure the scene exists

Comment: I'm seeing "LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T2_TOA" data over Antarctica https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2SXN.png

Comment: Please report some sample missing ids: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help_missing_images#landsat

Comment: Thank You for the URL, I reported it (specifically for LC08_L2SR_016117_20160216_20201016_02_T2 although as I said it is missing many others)

Comment: "Updated 5/3/22:" — Thanks for the update. But could you post that in the _answer_ box, instead of in the question? That makes it clearer that this question is resolved.